# Python Pandas - Sorting Issue KeyError:

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sort a panda data frame, but I'm getting KeyError. I want to be able to sort base on established conn and not the object name.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
j = '''
{
    "VSER-HTTP-80": {
        "established conn": "1",
        "external ip": "10.54.110.89",
        "external port": 80,
        "members": [
            {
                "current status": "UP",
                "name": "SER-APNTPS01",
                "server ip": "10.50.30.29",
                "service group name": "SVC-GRP-HTTP-80",
                "service name": null,
                "service port": 80,
                "service type": "HTTP"
            }
        ]
    },
    "VSER-SSL-443": {
        "established conn": "22",
        "external ip": "204.154.110.89",
        "external port": 443,
        "members": [
            {
                "current status": "UP",
                "name": "SER-APNTPS01",
                "server ip": "10.30.30.29",
                "service group name": "SVC-GRP-HTTP-80",
                "service name": null,
                "service port": 80,
                "service type": "HTTP"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''

df = pd.read_json(j)
df.sort(['established conn'])
```

Here is my index:

```
df.index
Index([u'established conn', u'external ip', u'external port', u'members'], dtype='object')
```

Here is my error:

```
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'established conn'
```

Comment: `df.sort()` sorts a dataframe either by index labels of by values in columns. You must pass either a column name or an index level. `['established conn']` is neither of them. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: My data consist of the following: I have name ex. VSER-HTTP-80, VSER-SSL-443 and I would like to filter so higher 'established conn' are showing first. In this example,  'VSER-SSL-443' should be first on the list. Maybe my data structure is not correct, but it just makes sense in JSON.

Comment: You confused rows and columns in your dataframe. You need `df.T.sort_values('established conn',ascending=False)`.

Comment: Thanks, that work.  What the T stand for.

Comment: Transpose the frame.